# Wondering why My CMS page will not display properly

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, page

I have designed a responsive Cms page Although, When I Add the Css to html inside  and save the page footer expands and 2 of the header buttons drop slightly Any solutions For an Example please see url. http://www.villalife.co.uk/abc

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what's happening pls?

Comment: Please avoid using link shorteners - for a good reason why (i.e. the link can point anywhere), see [this](https://goo.gl/dB59Q5) link.

Comment: Julien It wont allow me to upload screen shot. As you will be able to see from the url Footer has expanded and 2 buttons in header have dropped.

Comment: Apologies, www.villalife.co.uk/abc

Comment: Any other Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For responsive pages you cannot set a width and height to a specific pixel, no matter what screen resolution you view the page at the image will always be height:653 and width:980. You need to set your width to 100% and height to auto.

Setting the width 100% will keep the image inside the block its in.

this:

```
<img title="404 Error page" alt="404 Error" src="http://www.villalife.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/WYSIWYG/404_Error.jpg" height="653" width="980">
```

should be this:

```
<img title="404 Error page" alt="404 Error" src="http://www.villalife.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/WYSIWYG/404_Error.jpg" height="auto" width="100%">
```

[image]